# Regex to match series and number from a string starting with predefined characters

Tags: regex

Is it possible to match last series and number from a string that looks like:

```
 CUI: RO39890982                                   BZ 347
```

What I want: `BZ` and `347` from two separate regular expressions

What I'm trying: `CUI:[ ]*\s\S*\s(.*)`

What I get: `BZ 347`

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You say "two separate regular expressions", but you only show one. Did you try writing what you need? Why two? Why not a regex with *two capturing groups*?

Comment: I need two rules for extracting two separate values `BZ` and `347`... so far I haven't had any luck :(

Comment: Why do you need 2 regex if that can be done in a single regex with 2 capture groups?

Comment: Because I need to match the series prefix and then the series number. Two values using two regexes

Comment: What you have written proves you know all you need to write these patterns, `\S+`, `\s+`. You now know `$` (end of string). Just capture what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew regexr.com/64fab managed to get the series prefix `BZ` but it seems that `$` doesn't really help in this case.. or I don't really know how to use it

Comment: `CUI: *\S+ +([A-Z]+) +([0-9]+)$`  or `CUI: *\S+ +([A-Z]+) +([0-9]+)`  - this will match and capture both. Remove `(`/`)` that you do not need if you need to only have one capturing group per pattern.

Comment: `\bCUI:\s*\S+\s+([A-Z]+)\s+(\d+)` and grab both capture groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `347` with

```js
CUI: *\S+ +[A-Z]+ +(\d+)
```

Get `BZ` with

```js
CUI: *\S+ +([A-Z]+)
```

[Regex proof #1](https://regex101.com/r/tNhtr8/1), [regex proof #2](https://regex101.com/r/tNhtr8/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  CUI:                     'CUI:'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   +                       ' ' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]+                   any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   +                       ' ' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want two separate expressions:

**Regex 1** using `(\S+)` to capture 1 or more non whitspace chars in group 1:

```
CUI:\s*\S+\s+(\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gz2otE/1)

---

**Regex 2** Repeating a non capture group with a quantifier `{2}` with a nested capture group for the value

```
CUI:\s*\S+(?:\s+(\S+)){2}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7WKgDM/1)

Using the quantifier might be handy if you want to reuse it for more fields.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

***1st regex:*** To get `BZ` value: [Online demo for following regex](https://regex101.com/r/Sax4eL/1/)

```
\bCUI:\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex:

```
\bCUI:      ##Matching a word boundary with string CUI: here.
\s+\S+\s+   ##Matching 1 or more spaces followed by 1 or more non-spaces, followed by 1 or more spaces here.
(\S+)       ##Creating 1st capturing group which has 1 or more non-spaces here, which will catch BZ value here.
```

---

---

***2nd regex:*** To get `347` value(or similar pattern values) with shown samples.

```
\bCUI:\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\bCUI:     ##Matching a word boundary with string CUI: here.
\s+\S+\s+  ##Matching 1 or more spaces followed by 1 or more non-spaces, followed by 1 or more spaces here.
\S+\s+     ##matching 1 or non-spaces followed by 1 or more spaces here.
(\S+)      ##Creating 1st capturing group which has 1 or more non-spaces here, which will catch 347 value here.
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/jvzVl9/1)